# What's wrong with this MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

So what is wrong with this trigger? MySQL is only nice enough to tell me it is a 1064 error.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER new_member BEFORE INSERT on member
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO party(PartyId, PartyTypeCode, DateCreated, DateUpdated) 
     VALUES(New.PartyId, ’M’,now(), now());
END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Could you be so nice and show us **the exact error**?

Comment: Not much to show....#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEFORE INSERT on member FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO party(PartyId, Part' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that your problem is the non-ASCII quotes in your `VALUES`:

```
VALUES(New.PartyId, ’M’,now(), now());
-- -----------------^
```

Try using plain old single quotes like SQL expects:

```
VALUES(New.PartyId, 'M', now(), now());
```

Comment: The quote format is a result of copy/paste, I made sure to do as you suggest though and still the same.

Comment: I'm more of an Oracle guy, but I know you get this issue exists if you type some sql up in MS Word, and then someone tries to copy and paste it into Oracle. -Edit: Didn't see your comment enfield until after I poseted mine...

Comment: @enfield: There's nothing else wrong with your trigger syntax. Are you certain that all the spaces are real ASCII `\x20`s (i.e. spaces) and not some Unicode character that looks like a space? What are you editing your SQL in?

Comment: @Windle: You're thinking that sometimes a space isn't a space even though it looks like one? That's my next guess.

Comment: @mu is too short, you were right here, I started typing in an rtf doc before copying into CodeBox to finish it up.  Retyped all in CodeBox/SQL and that error is gone.

Comment: @muistooshort : ya, whenever I've taken sql written in anything besides an IDE designed for it, or a simple editor like notepad, there always seems to be some weird meta-characters thrown in there you can't see by default, or fancy apostophres, etc.

Comment: @Windle: I'm lucky, my fingers think in `vi` so everything non-trivial is always just plain text for me and I don't have to worry about all that fancy stuff (that has no place in source code).